# why does a bash backend function return failure when its parent is dead

Tags: bash, nohup

I want to make a bash function continue running even when ssh timeouts or terminal is closed. Because I don't want to create a new script file to call it separately, I used the nohup and '&' method to achieve my goal.

```
(
  trap "" HUP
  sleep 10
  echo 'abc123!' | sudo -S -p '' bash -c "cat /etc/shadow"
  ret=$?
  if [ $ret -ne 0 ]; then
     echo "failed-->$ret" >> /tmp/test.log
  fi
)&
```

The above is only part of my script, representing those need to continue running after its parent is dead.
The script is run by a non-root user, so need to use sudo to execute some commands. 
This script returns successfully when its parent is alive. 
But when you close the terminal when it is running, you will get 'failed-->1" in the test.log file after the child process exits.
So, can anybody tell me what's wrong with the script?

Comment: Some of this is implementation dependant, so I can't say this is a definitive answer.  Normally the signal mask (ignored signals) is inherited by child processes, but `sudo` does its own signal handling and will override your `trap`.  A SIGHUP sent by a user process will be relayed to the command it is running - but on your system do a `man sudo` and search for `Signal Handling` for the authoritative answer.

Comment: Try `shopt -u huponexit`

Comment: Just curious, why do you need the `bash -c`?  `cat` is an external program unconnected to `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer my own question. I solved this issue, but still not sure about the root cause.
I changed the code of 'sudo' to:

```
echo 'abc123!' | sudo -S -p '' cat /etc/shadow > /tmp/test.log 2>&1
```

The possible reason is when closing the terminal, the standard output is broken, need to assign a new standard output explicitly.